# How to hide the facebook authorization dialog on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm implementing facebook connect for my iPhone app. The current facebook SDK would keep you logged in unless you log out explicitly, which is fine with me as stay logged in is actually the requirement. However, I don't want the users to go press the log in button if they never logged out. In this case, I won't be able to grab the facebook object, which I'll need in other parts of my app. So I was planning to simulate the log in event anyways, but that led me to another problem: even though permissions are granted to my facebook app before, it will still pop up the authorization dialog to my users saying they have granted permissions to my app. My question is, how do I hide this? Or, is there a way that I can grab the valid facebook object without calling authorize on my facebook object when my app is restarted and the user stayed logged in?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to reread the docs. You can get the facebook object without the login button

Comment: Hi coneybeare, can you point me to the doc where they explain this? I have gone through the iOS SDK doc for so many times and still couldn't seem to find anything. Am I skipping something?

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the user to `https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=<YOUR_APP_ID>`. (This is the URL that the PHP Facebook SDK returns when you call `getLoginUrl()`).This will avoid the dialog and still allow users to authorize your app.

Comment: I think I understand what you meant, and I believe that's what Facebook SDK for Blackberry does. However, I'm new to iPhone and not sure at which step I should do this. Can you give more hints on it? Thanks.